# Convert Scss variables to css variables during build time using webpack

Tags: css, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I am in the process of changing my scss variable to css variables during build using webpack! Is there any way I can do this so that I can replace my scss variable to css variables dynamically (automated) not manually.

I've used string-replace-loader with regex to mutate in every file but got no success.
I've used string interpolation

```
$color-black: #000000;

body {
    --color-black: #{$color-black};
}
```

I want during build time change all scss varaibles to css variables like below

```
.dev{
  color:$color-black;
}
```

to

```
.dev{
 color: var(--color-black);
}
```

Thanks in advance
Appologise if question is repeated

Comment: No, there's none. My question is: What's the point of using a Sass variable in those scenarios, if you want them to be changed to CSS' anyway?

Comment: Thanks @Simplicius , Actually project was completed and now the demand is of white labeling ! So I want to change sass vars to css vars !